# About metric space and finite subset

Tags: real-analysis

I'm sorry i cant solve this problem. Thank you.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. We say that $A$ is bounded if there is $M>0$ such that $d(a,a')\leq M$ for all $a$,$a'$ in $A$. Show that if $A_1,\dots,A_n$ with $n < \infty$ all are bounded subsets of $X$, show that $A_1\cup  \dots \cup A_n$ is also a bounded subset of $X$.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hint: Select one point for each of the subsets and use the fact that finite sets of reals always have a maximum. Then use the triangle inequality to extend to all pairs of points.

Comment: Don't think metric and bounded has anything to do with it.

Comment: can you show me some steps to elaborate more? thanks a lot. @celtsshk

Comment: @fleablood sorry i dont understand

Comment: @Kylie: You wrote "finite subset" where you obviously meant "bounded subset". Actually I didn't notice that, but fleablood took your question as you wrote it. Being finite just means there are finitely many elements, and then you indeed don't need any metric or boundedness to prove the claim as stated (as opposed to as meant).

Comment: @Kylie: About elaborating more: Robert Z. already did in his answer.

Comment: It never even occurred to me when the OP said A_1 to A_2.... to A_n were "finite" s/he could have meant "bounded".  It's a very standard (albeit it tedious and vague) exercise of cardinality that the finite union of finite sets is finite, by mapping finite sets of natural numbers to the individual elements of the sets.  This clearly has *nothing* to do with metrics or boundedness or even anything to do with the values of the elements of the set.

Comment: @fleablood: If the exercise were to prove something about cardinality, then what would be the point of introducing the metric and the definition of boundedness?

Comment: That's what confused me.  I figured the OP didn't know it had nothing to do with metrics so I was telling him/her that was a red herring and not relevant.  Of course, realizing s/he meant "bounded" it makes perfect sense.  But is an entirely *different* problem.  ... Anyway it's been corrected and Robert Z has given an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show that if $A_1,\dots,A_n$ with $n < \infty$ all are bounded subsets of $X$, show that $A_1\cup  \dots \cup A_n$ is also a bounded subset of $X$.

For $i=1,2,\dots n$, let $A_i$ be a bounded with $d(a,a')\leq M_i$ for all $a,a'\in A_i$. 
For any $i$, choose a point $a_i$ in $A_i$ (we assume that $A_i$ is non-empty) and let
$$r:=\max_{1\leq i<j\leq n} d(a_i,a_j).$$
Now let $x,y \in A_1\cup\dots \cup A_n$ then $x\in A_i$ and $y\in A_j$ for some $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

Hence, by triangular inequality,
$$d(x,y)\leq d(x,a_i)+d(a_i,a_j)+d(a_j,y)\leq M_i+r+M_j\leq R:=r+2\max_{1\leq i\leq n} {M_i}$$
and we may conclude that $A_1\cup\dots \cup A_n$ is bounded with a finite constant $R$.

Comment: you mean finite subset = bounded subset?

Comment: @Kylie A finite union of finite set is always finite. I think that your problem is about the BOUNDEDNESS of the union. Check your statement.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you'll also need to treat the case that any $A_i$ is empty (empty sets are bounded, but of course you cannot select a point from them). Fortunately that case is trivial (an empty set doesn't change the union).

Comment: @celtschk Good point, I edited my answer.

Comment: finite absolutely does **NOT** equal bounded.  Not even remotely.  However proving that the finite union of finite sets has absolutely *NOTHING* is do with metrics and boundedness, that the introduction to this problem being so irrelevant make Rbert Z and celltsshk fairly certain that you must have misstated the problem.  Your question sounds like "We often classify animals by their diets.  An animal that consumes animals is called a carniverous while those with a mixed diet are called omnivorous.  Explain why in forests many animals might be nocturnal."